# Designing Buck Converter with Adjustable Output Current and Output Voltage

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pwm, buck, constant-current

I am currently attempting to design a buck converter where both the output current and output voltage can be simultaneously adjusted. I will be utilizing an Arduino for control. I figured some sort of IC would be required to achieve this digitally (don't want to utilize manual potentiometer type designs). I am currently considering utilizing an LT8613 chip. Here is the datasheet for reference: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8613f.pdf

Running a simulation for a digitally controlled voltage/current source with this chip, I am having trouble figuring out how to control the output V and I. I know the Ictrl pin is directly responsible for output current, and the feedback resistor network for the output voltage, but changing one is effecting the other quite a bit. To be more specific, I am considering utilizing digital potentiometers for the feedback resistor network.

Any guidance, tips, etc. on this would be appreciated. The application is a Lithium-Ion battery charger. Max output current of 5A, max output voltage of 4.2 volts. Also, can something like this be achieved without an IC?

Comment: So you know you either have adjustable voltage or current at any time, not both simultaneously?

Comment: You don't need to control the voltage. If you want to be really fancy, you COULD adjust it based on cell temperature. But all you need to do is set a MAX current limit of 5A and a max Voltage of 4.2. The IC will simultaneously enforce both limits. There is a lot more to charging a lithium ion battery, though. You need to monitor output current so that you can terminate charging when battery acceptance drops sufficiently. I think you need to spend some time reading up on how Lithium batteries are charged. Also, if you are buying an IC anyway, why not just buy a LiPo charger IC?

Comment: I know that you can do this without an IC .In fact it was easier to stabilise .